# How do I set the Docker disk size in Ubuntu CLI?

Tags: linux, docker, hyperledger-fabric, docker-container

[Docker taking space - image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERzgD.jpg)

Is their way to set the Docker Disk Image size been used using CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, You can create a volume and attach it to your container.
As in docker documentation you can create volume like this

```
docker volume create --driver local \
--opt type=tmpfs \
--opt device=tmpfs \
--opt o=size=100m,uid=1000 \
foo
```

And attach it to you container using the -v option on docker run command

```
docker run -d -v foo:/world busybox
```

you can find a description for each option in the docker documentation it's a one of the greatest reference you could find https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/